# How to transpose JSON structs and arrays in PySpark

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Json file that I'm reading into a dataframe.

```
{
  "details": {
    "box": [
      {
        "Touchdowns": "123",
        "field": "Texans"
      },
      {
        "Touchdowns": "456",
        "field": "Ravens"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Team"
}
```

How could I manipulate this to get the following output?

| Team | Touchdowns |
| --- | --- |
| Texans | 123 |
| Ravens | 456 |

I'm struggling a bit with whether I need to pivot/transpose the data or if there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: FYI, they are called *objects*, not structs, in JSON.

Comment: @chepner they are structs when read into spark

Comment: Once they're in spark, it's not JSON anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the multiline json into spark

```
df = spark.read.json('/path/to/scores.json',multiLine=True)
```

Schema

```
df:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
    details:struct
        box:array
           element:struct
               Touchdowns:string
               field:string
     name:string
```

All of the info you want is in the first row, so get that and drill down to details and box and make that your new dataframe.

```
spark.createDataFrame(df.first()['details']['box']).withColumnRenamed('field','Team').show()
```

Output

```
+----------+------+
|Touchdowns|  Team|
+----------+------+
|       123|Texans|
|       456|Ravens|
+----------+------+
```

Comment: I should have been a bit more explicit, but is there any way to have the name:string, which in this case is "Team" to be the column header instead of renaming the column. The json will repeat and the name:string will be a different column name. The array structure will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `inline` function.

```
df = spark.read.load(json_file_path, format='json', multiLine=True)
df = df.selectExpr('inline(details.box)').withColumnRenamed('field', 'Team')
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a `rdd` to get the values of `box` `list`.

***Input JSON***

```
jsonstr="""{
  "details": {
    "box": [
      {
        "Touchdowns": "123",
        "field": "Texans"
      },
      {
        "Touchdowns": "456",
        "field": "Ravens"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Team"
}"""
```

Now convert it to an `rdd` using the keys of `dictionary` as below -

```
import json
box_rdd = sc.parallelize(json.loads(jsonstr)['details']['box'])
box_rdd.collect()

Output - [{'Touchdowns': '123', 'field': 'Texans'},
 {'Touchdowns': '456', 'field': 'Ravens'}]
```

Finally create the dataframe with this `box_rdd` as below -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([StructField('Touchdowns', StringType(), True), StructField('field', StringType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=box_rdd,schema=schema)
df.show()

+----------+------+
|Touchdowns| field|
+----------+------+
|       123|Texans|
|       456|Ravens|
+----------+------+
```